# Join 3 tables in mysql/php issue

Tags: php, mysql

I need to join 3 tables and show all the data :

The following query works fine. Here i have joined 2 tables called "comparitive_statement1" and "comparitive_st_sup". Here the total everything is fine.

```
SELECT tc.*,sum(tci.total_inr) as tot1, tci.supplier_name,tci.currency as currency2 FROM comparitive_statement1 tc INNER JOIN comparitive_st_sup tci ON tc.tender_id=tci.tender_id WHERE tc.tender_id='$tender_id' and tc.sup_name=tci.supplier_name GROUP BY tc.sup_name ORDER BY tc.sup_name ASC
```

Now i need to join one more table called "comparitive_st_tech_compliance" with same tender_id and supplier_name. Here when i join my totals are wrong. Placing the query which i have done:

```
SELECT tc.*, sum(tci.total_inr) as tot1, tci.supplier_name,tci.currency as currency2 FROM comparitive_statement1 tc INNER JOIN comparitive_st_sup tci ON tc.tender_id=tci.tender_id INNER JOIN comparitive_st_tech_compliance cl ON tci.tender_id=cl.tender_id and tc.sup_name=cl.supplier_name WHERE tc.tender_id='$tender_id'  GROUP BY tc.sup_name,cl.supplier_name ORDER BY tc.sup_name ASC
```

What iam doing wrong?

Comment: Whats wrong with your query, are you getting any error ?

Comment: It's a guess:  tender_id is not unique in comparitive_st_tech_compliance or there are tender_id in other tables, wich are not in comparitive_st_tech_compliance table or both. In first case tot1 would be smaller and in second greater (asuming total_inr is positive). If both are true...

Comment: Presumably there are multiple rows in compliance for each total. Note that you should always group by the column which appears in the select - and not one from another table as you are doing. Incidentally, 'comparitive' isn't a word

Answer (score 0):

could be the  `and tc.sup_name=cl.supplier_name` part

try

```
   INNER JOIN comparitive_st_tech_compliance cl ON 
   tci.tender_id=cl.tender_id and tc1.supplier_name=cl.supplier_name
```

Comment: No its not..i tried to change it but its showing the same totals